# QBSDK: Access all transactions of all clients (date period)

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I need to look at the "audit" log for quickbooks using the SDK. I am basically looking to sync quickbooks transactions to a 3rd party platform (for reference purposes)

I cant find a reference to the audit log in the OSR, but I do see "TransactionsQuery". What is not clear to me is if this will be "all" transactions, or if you need to specify a specific customer?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As William indicated in his answer, the audit log is accessible via a `GeneralDetailReport`.

As far as actual transactions goes, `TransactionQuery` will get you *all* transactions. You *do not* need to specify a customer.

*However*, it will only get you summary details of all transactions (e.g. no line items on the invoices, etc.) so if you need detailed information for each transaction, it won't work for you.

If you need details for each transaction, you have to do individual queries for each transaction type (e.g. `InvoiceQuery`, `ReceivePaymentQuery`, `BillQuery`, etc. etc. etc.) so that you get back the details/lines for each.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the GeneralDetailReport, with the GeneralDetailReportType set to AuditTrail.